Product of Sobolev functions $W_0^{1,p}$ and $W^{1,p}\cap L^\infty$
I have found two statements about products of Sobolev functions.

In Evans & Gariepy's Measure Theory Section 4.2.2, $u,v\in W^{1,p}\cap L^\infty$ implies $uv\in W^{1,p}$.
In Evans PDE Section 5.2.3, $u\in W^{1,p}$, $v\in C_c^\infty$ implies $uv\in W^{1,p}$. (I believe $uv\in W_0^{1,p}$ in this case?)

It is not true if we drop $L^\infty$ in Case 1. Counterexamples can be found in Product of Sobolev functions
My question is: does $uv\in W^{1,p}$ if we assume $u\in W_0^{1,p}$, $v\in W^{1,p}\cap L^\infty$?
Thank you in adanvce for any proof or counterexamples.

Added: The following only works if we assume that $u\in L^\infty$ as well.
Yes: If $u_n\in C_c^\infty$ approximates $u$ and $v_n\in C^\infty$ approximates $v$, then $u_nv_n\in C_c^\infty$ converges weakly to $uv$. Since $W^{1,p}_0$ is weakly closed, this means $uv\in W^{1,p}_0$.

Sorry I'm not very familiar with weak convergence in $W_0^{1,p}$, do you mean $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \int D_i (u_n v_n) \phi_i = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \int ((D_i u_n) v_n + u_n D_i v_n) \phi_i = \int ((D_i u)v + u (D_i v)) \phi_i$ for $\phi_i \in L^{p'}$. Then how to show $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \int u_n(D_i v_n)\phi_i = \int u (D_i v)\phi_i$ if we do not have uniform $L^\infty$ bound on $u_n$ and $u$? Am I on the right track ……

@Expialidocius: Sorry, you're right that in the absence of $L^\infty$ bounds on $u$ my argument doesn't (and shouldn't by ktoi's counterexample) work.

Firstly, this is false if we merely have $u \in W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$ and $v \in W^{1,p}(\Omega) \cap L^{\infty}(\Omega)$; you also need $u$ to be bounded. To see this, take e.g. $\Omega = B(0,1) \subset \mathbb R^2$ and  $p=3/2$. Then consider
$$ u(x) = \eta(x)\frac1{|x|^{1/4}}, \quad v(x) = \frac{x_1}{\lvert x \rvert},$$
where $\eta \in C^{\infty}_c(B(0,1))$ is a smooth cutoff such that $\eta \equiv 1$ on $B(0,1/2)$.
Then one can verify that $u \in W_0^{1,3/2}(\Omega)$ and $v \in W^{1,3/2}(\Omega) \cap L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ while the product
$$ (uv)(x)  = \eta(x) \frac{x_1}{|x|^{5/4}}$$
does not lie in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$, by verifying that
$$\partial_{x_1}(uv) = \frac{1}{|x|^{5/4}} - \frac54 \frac{x_1^2}{|x|^{13/4}}  \quad\text{in } B(0,1/2),$$
which is not $L^p$-integrable near the origin.

The result is true however, if you assume that $u \in W^{1,p}_0(\Omega) \cap L^{\infty}(\Omega)$. The main modification from the usual proof is to approximate $u$ by functions in $C^{\infty}_c(\Omega)$ with a uniform $L^{\infty}$ bound.
By definition, there is a sequence $(u_n) \subset C^{\infty}_c(\Omega)$ such that $u_n \to u$ in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$.
Now letting $M > \lVert u \rVert_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)}$, define the truncation operator
$$ Tv(x) =\max\{-M,\min\{v(x),M\}\}= \begin{cases} -M &\text{if } v(x) <- M, \\ v(x) &\text{if } \lvert v(x) \rvert \leq M, \\ +M &\text{if } v(x)>M.
\end{cases} $$
Then since each $u_n$ is compactly supported and smooth, we have $Tu_n$ is also compactly supported.
By the chain rule for Sobolev functions, we have each $Tu_n \in W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ and also $Tu_n \to Tu$ in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$. However by our choice of $M$, we have $Tu = u$. Now by mollifying each $Tu_n$, we can find $\tilde u_n \in C^{\infty}_c(\Omega)$ such that $\lVert u_n - \tilde u_n \rVert_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)} < \frac1n$. Then it follows that $\tilde u_n \to u$ in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$, and we have $\lVert \tilde u_n \rVert_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)} \leq M$ for all $n$.
Then taking $v_n \in C^{\infty}(\Omega) \cap W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ such that $v_n \to v$ in $W^{1,p}$ and $\lVert v_n \rVert \leq C$ for all $n$ (e.g. by a similar construction to above), we can argue that $u_nv_n \to uv$ weakly in $W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$ as the other answer sketches.

About $\partial_{x_1}(uv)\not\in L^{\frac{3}{2}}$. Doesn't $-\frac{5}{4}\cdot \frac{3}{2} = -\frac{15}{8} > -2 = -n$ imply that both $\frac{1}{|x|^{\frac{5}{4}}}$ and $\frac{x_1^2}{|x|^{\frac{13}{4}}} \in L^{\frac{3}{2}}$?

@Expialidocius You're right, this example doesn't work. It looks like power-type functions aren't enough, so I will need to think about how to fix this.
